# What are the consequences of using a small bootstrap capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator, switching-regulator

I ordered the wrong bootstrap capacitor for a [LM2677S-5.0/NOPB regulator](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/LM2677S-5-0-NOPB/363818). They recommend a 100 nF cap, but I ordered 10 nF.

What are the consequences of using the smaller value?

Comment: I've always been a bit puzzled by the sometimes large, and sometimes very particular values some datasheets give (e.g. I've seen 150nF specified). You can always measure it and see if the boost voltage is dropping off much; the waveform on the boost pin should simply be biased up from the switch node. Also, two probes can be used for a differential measurement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typical bootstrap capacitors would be much smaller - just 0.1uF (100 nF, that is, *nano* farads.)

(ok, I see you fixed that uF vs. nF confusion.)

They mention Cboot / Cboost value three times in the datasheet:

- Diagram says 0.01uF (10nF)
- Pin Description says 100nF.
- Later in the datsheet, 0.01uF.

Inconsistent? Yes. (Tsk, tsk, TI.)

This would seem to be authoritative:

> 7.3.2 CBoost
>
> A capacitor must be connected from pin 3 to the switch output, pin 1. This capacitor boosts the gate driver to the internal MOSFET above VIN to fully turn it ON. This minimizes conduction losses in the power switch to maintain high efficiency. The recommended value for CBoost is 0.01 μF.

from here: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2677.pdf

So I think it'll be ok with 10nF. 100nF is reasonable too.

If in your testing with 10nF you see a problem (like excessive power dissipation in the IC, or not enough full-load output), the bootstrap voltage may be drooping excessively during high-drive time.

To correct it you can try tacking on additional 10nF in parallel (or, try 100nF) to get more 'boot' to run the high-side drive to see if your supply behaves better.

Comment: Here is a link to the datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2677.pdf